# How do I access the original point in periodic 2 D Triangulation in CGAL?

Tags: cgal, triangulation

I did the periodic triangulation of five points with the default domain.The points were `(0.2,0.3)`, `(0.5,0.1)`, `(0.7,0.6)`, `(0.8,0.8)`, `(0.5,0.11)`. After iterating over the faces for 1 sheeted covering and printing the output, I got this result:

`0.8 0.8` , `0.7 0.6` , `1.2 1.3` and so on.

I know the points `1.2 1.3` means the point `0.2 0.3` as the domain is iso_ rectangle. But I want it to print `0.2 0.3` instead of `1.2 1.3` so that I could find the delaunay neighbours of a given vertex.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vertex v of the periodic triangulation t, then t.periodic_point(v) gives you a periodic point, whose first element is a point in the original domain. I guess that this point is what you are looking for. 
See
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Periodic_2_triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Periodic__2__triangulation__2.html#a217b56b0d5a8c222573f520a69a696ee
and
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Periodic_2_triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Periodic__2__triangulation__2.html#abc48042ca1cff117f7c5201c0ffdabfa